# Unable to decompress gzip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I am not able to decompress a gzip file using Python gzip library.

This is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
import gzip

# Open the gzip file in binary mode
with gzip.open("2023-04-25_xyz.log.gz", 'rb') as f:
    # Read the compressed data
    compressed_data = f.read()
    # Decompress the data
    decompressed_data = gzip.decompress(compressed_data)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhasa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    decompressed_data = gzip.decompress(compressed_data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 556, in decompress
    return f.read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 300, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 487, in read
    if not self._read_gzip_header():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 435, in _read_gzip_header
    raise BadGzipFile('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'Ti')
```

Comment: Do you have access to `gzip` via the terminal?  If yes, what happens when you use that to attempt the unzip?

Comment: Did you check the file downloaded correctly? It looks like it could be a gzipped log file. Are you able to read it using `zcat` on the command line?

Comment: The file is on Mac. Archive utility is able to decompress it.

Comment: The gzip command via terminal is also able to decompress it.

Comment: @moo - zcat is not able to read it.

Comment: `compressed_data = f.read()` is simply wrong.  The whole POINT of using `gzip.open()` is that the file is decompressed as it is read; you don't need to decompress it again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'Ti')

indicates that the input starts with 2 bytes: ASCII `T` and `i`. Valid gzip files have different starting 2 bytes: hex 0x1F and 0x8B. Thus the `compressed_data` string in line 8 is not of the gzip format.

This is not a surprise, because `compressed_data` is in fact uncompressed: the file has been decompressed already by `gzip.open` + `read`. Calling `gzip.decompress` on the result of that tries to decompress it once again. That can only succeed if the file was compressed twice, e.g. with `<file gzip -c | gzip -c >file.gz.gz`.

Here is how to fix your code:

```py
import gzip
with gzip.open("2023-04-25_xyz.log.gz", 'rb') as f:
    decompressed_data = f.read()
```

Or, alternatively:

```py
import gzip
with open("2023-04-25_xyz.log.gz", 'rb') as f:
    decompressed_data = gzip.decompress(f.read())
```

Comment: `gzip.decompress` isn't operating on the raw data from the file: it's operating on the data *after* the implicit decompression performed by using `gzip.open`. Trying to decompress that a second time fails.  The file itself would appear to be fine - if it wasn't a proper gz file, then an error would likely be thrown on the previous line with `compressed_data = f.read()`.